# sufficient subsample size for given sample to obtain same regression

Tags: regression, small-sample

I am performing an engineering analysis to find out the effect of earthquake on concrete buildings. Analysis applies earthquake forces on building model for 50 earthquakes, resulting into separate 50 analyses. Earthquake intensity is independent variable of study. building drift, extracted from analysis, is dependent variable. Regression on (drift, intensity) result using OLS regression for 50 results, gives simple linear relationship: ln(drift) = β0+β1*ln(intensity). This log linear relationship is well established in field of earthquake engineering. Each analysis is a time consuming process because it involves material non-linearity and dynamic analysis. Hence I am looking for method that can check whether the regression using lesser number of analysis result (say 35 or 40) is statistically similar to 50 sample regression. I came up with folllowing process -

1) generate 10000 samples of 50 data points by replacement. regress all 10000 samples and find out mean and variance of intercept and slope. lets say its β0_50 SD_β0_50 and β1_50 SD_β1_50.

2) generate 10000 samples of 45 (or any other number less than original data size) data points with replacement. regress these 10000 samples and obtain β0_45 SD_β0_45 and β1_45 SD_β1_45.

3) Compare β0_50 with β0_45 and β1_50 with β1_45 using z-statistics.

Please suggest if such an approach makes sense statistically. I am an engineer by training and not sure if I violated some basic principles of bootstrap or z-statistics comparison.

Any suggestion about the standard process/tests to establish adequate subsample size is welcome.

Appreciate your comments, time and efforts.

Comment: I read this as meaning that, at present, each building design is hit with 50 earthquakes using simulation software, and those simulations - using known but CPU-heavy time-consuming material equations - are then used to determine the log-linear equation parameters by regression, but it is not certain that 50 simulations are needed for minimum statistical confidence in those regression results. Is this essentially correct? My background is in nuclear engineering and industrial radiation physics, so please forgive me for asking as this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Right James, that's what my exact problem is. In future, I want to evaluate reaponse of several different building configurations (different buildings in plan dimension and height) . But because of large simulation time want to reduce number of simulation for each building type. How to obtain that number statistcally is my problem.

Comment: My suggestion is to make a preliminary investigation exactly as you have described, to investigate the difference in 50 and 45 (or 40). It is theoretically possible that 50 yields insufficient statistical certainty in the regression parameters for your engineering purpose, I consider this unlikely, and advise making a determination of the minimum necessary parameter certainty needed as part of this preliminary engineering analysis.

Comment: I tried working on this approach. But One confusing aspect is calculation of z value. z = (mean1-mean2)/sqrt(SD1^2/n1+SD2^2/n2). where mean, SD and n represent mean, standard deviation and sample size. Here bootstrap sample size is very large, say 10000. This makes denominator very large and thus almost all values of sub-sample number is failing test. Am I correct in using bootstrap sample size here. Or should I use 50 and 45 instead.

Additionally, as per your suggestion, How minimum necessary parameters can be ascertained.

Thanks.